# How to get this data in a list?

Tags: python, list, csv, slice

I am new to Python and got the following data to work with:

**https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86876232/6358.csv**

The linked file is only a fraction of the entire data (the data should contain a bit over 15000 lists). First of all in what format is this data? And how do I get it from that format into lists so I can slice the volume data out.

When I use a module to read the csv data, I get not every list as separate list, but one big list, with every list as a value.

And this is how the data looks like: 4;"false";"null";"null";"Osebni avto";"20";"PoboÄje";"5.0";"3-9m3  (velikost osebnega avtomobila)";"3.0";"null";"30";"10";"10";"null";"null";"null";"50";"false";"

And if it is better to have it in a dictionary how am I going to do this? There is no key in the data which I can assign to the value. The information consist purely of different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv

I'm not quite sure why this is downvoted so much?

Your best bet is to avoid manually reading in csv files and just use one of the default modules python has for reading them in. There's quite a lot of code snippets for using csv around the net so you should have any issues. Also I think you'll be better off with dictionaries than lists.

Comment: @Robin The reasons why you're having problems were obvious to me the second I opened that csv file. Usually csv files. 
They usually look like this:

#name, age (this line is optional)
"Name","Age"
"David","48"
"Don","46"
"Sue","39"

Yours looks like 

data;data;data;
<p> Some weird p tag </p>
data;data;data
Something just randomly written in

The csv file is a mess and therefore csv.DictReader has problems reading through it.

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: @Robin: I don't know, this is just a collection of random data basically. Someone just automatically clicked "make csv" or "export as csv" and now you have all your data in the 1st field and then just  a bunch of commas stringed to end of it so it "looks" like a csv file with n fields. Take a look at your file in a notepad, and make sure you have line wrap turned off. 

You will notice that you have lines like <p>foobar</p>,,,, and lines with some actual data "4"";""null"";",,,, The separators of this file are the commas, because the ; are commented out. Contact whoever sent you that csv file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will then now contact the person, and see if this time a proper csv file can be send.